# How to add / create table in the current database in mysql?

Tags: mysql-5.6, table

mySQL 5.6.24: Could anyone guide me on that "How to create a base view and table for a specific plugin?"

After uploading the plug-in, I'm getting following error:

> "There has been an error processing your request SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base
>   table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'yuvakxkb_mage800.mgjm_manthan_marketplace_seller' doesn't exist,

query was:

```
SELECT `main_table`.* 
FROM `mgjm_manthan_marketplace_seller` AS `main_table` 
WHERE (`user_id` = '1')"
```

How can I create a base view and table for the above error in MySQL?

Comment: Are you sure that you are executing a query in the correct database? Is this "yuvakxkb_mage800" correct database/schema for your table?

Comment: Yes, DB Name is yuvakxkb_mage800 .

Answer (score 0):

Is this Magento?  I had a similar issue where the plugin I was using wasn't compatible with the version of Magento that was installed.

Check your plugin compatibility then if you're running this on a hosted platform, use phpMyAdmin to verify that the table actually exists.

Also, have you contacted the Magento forums to see if they can help?

Comment: That plugin uses mysql 5.4 and I'm running 5.6.24. I changed the database version but it didn't help. Now it is stuck at base table view as mentioned earlier.